# indexing after concatenation MAPLE

Tags: arrays, maple

I have concatenated three arrays in maple to form a larger array using the statement:
basic := Concatenate(2, list1, c, d);(list1,c,d are the arrays and 2 means concatenate in second dimension, which I don't quite understand)

Now I have got basic:=[x,y,z,x+y,x+z,y+z,x-y,x-z,y-z] but the type of basic is symbol.
It means that it is an unindexed name and I will not be able to loop basic[i].
Maple says "error, unevaluated array index in assignment"

I hope to index the concatenated array or be able to loop from "x" .. "y-z" by other means

Thanks in advance
Tim

Comment: Please post your code in full.

Comment: Thanks for being concerned. I have solved this problem.